# Does Python's MSSQL module support Microsoft 2000 SQL Server communication?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, sql-server-2000

We have an old `Microsoft 2000 SQL Server` at the office that we want to use in sync with a new `Python` program for depositing some log data. I was wondering if there is a specific `Python` module for connecting with older versions of `Microsoft's SQL Servers` or if current modules like `MSSQL` will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

I think your options are pyodbc ([found here](https://mkleehammer.github.io/pyodbc/)) and pymssql ([found here](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/)). I don't think there are any in-betweens or other options. As far as whether it works-- I would assume so, but only because mssql2k was released so long ago, and depends on the odbc framework. I can't guarantee success, but it's certainly a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks. Will try it out